# Typedef Generalisation

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, typedef

I need to generalise a C++ typedef so I do not need to copy and paste a lot of code.  I am serializing blitz arrays using boost and I am defining my own load and save methods and need to do this based on template parameters.  Basically I don't know how to generalize

```
typedef blitz::Array<double, 2> my_Matrix;
```

for higher order tensors ie, I want to generalise the above so that it will take 1,2,..,n and if possible do the same for the type.

I guess I am chasing something like a typedef template.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know much about blitz array but you should be able to put the typedef inside a templated struct. E.g. something like:

```
template<int N>
struct Matrix
{
    typedef blitz::Array<double,N> Type;
};
```

Use like thus `Matrix<3>::Type`.

As for your other question regarding serialisation, looking at the documentation for array:

http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/manual/blitz02.html

it looks like you can just replace the rows * cols test for size with a call to size(). The data() method should still work for matrices of rank > 2.

Answer (score 0):

C++0x has it:

```
template <size_t N>
using MyMatrix<N> = blitz::Array<double,N>;
```

However you'll still need a template method for `load` and `save` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A typedef is really just creating another name for something. It isn't quite like doing a `#define`, but its close. Being just another name, you can't really do anything with them that you couldn't do with the exact name they are replacing.

What you could do is go all the way and use `#define`. Like so:

```
#define my_Matrix(X) blitz::Array<X>
```

Personally, I hate the preprocessor, and would prefer it be removed from the language.